# How to loop through simpy events triggering a resource usage

Tags: python, simpy

This code works....

```
class FA(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.resource1 = simpy.Resource(env, 10)
        self.resource2 = simpy.Resource(env, 20)

    def do_process1(self, tray):
        yield self.env.timeout(50)

    def do_process2(self, tray):
        yield self.env.timeout(100)

def do_FA(env, fa, tray):
    with fa.resource1.request() as request:
        yield request
        yield env.process(fa.do_process1(tray))

    with fa.resource2.request() as request:
        yield request
        yield env.process(fa.do_process2(tray))

def run_FA(env):
    fa = FA(env)
    tray = 0

    while True:
        tray += 1
        env.process(do_FA(env, fa, tray))
        time_between_trays = 12
        yield env.timeout(time_between_trays)

env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(run_FA(env))
env.run(until=20000)
```

etc...

Is there a way to shorten the function do_FA? Since I have tens of resources and processes, I want to create a list of processes and associated resources and iterate through them?

Comment: short answer is yes
you can assign function to variables or list, just drop the () at the end of the function.
Once assigned to a var you can use that var as the function. You can use tuples to pair the function with a resource and put the tuple into your list.

I am a bit busy now, but will write up a demo.  However, building the list will take as much trouble as writing the original function

Comment: Just in case someone had the same question, I was able to acheive what I wanted using getattr and setattr.

Comment: can you add your solution as a answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what your want to do is reduce the boiler plate code down to 1 line.  In the case of do_FA that would be to reduce its 6 lines of code to only 2.

My solution is to create a helper function that does the boiler plate stuff, and call that function.

here is my example based on your example

```
"""
    quick demo to show how boiler plate code for geting and using a resource
    can be wrapped in a helper function

    Programer Michael R. Gibbs
"""

import simpy

class FA(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.resource1 = simpy.Resource(env, 10)
        self.resource2 = simpy.Resource(env, 20)

    def do_process1(self, tray):
        yield self.env.timeout(50)
        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} tray: {tray} did process 1')

    def do_process2(self, tray):
        yield self.env.timeout(100)
        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} tray: {tray} did process 2')

def use_resource(env, res, res_func):
    """
        wraps the resource boiler plate code, the :
            get request
            get resouse
            do function
        as one fuction call

        res: the resource to be used, 
        res_func: The fuction to be called when the resource is aquired

        note that res_func is really a generator because it has a yield in it
    """

    with res.request() as req:
        yield req
        yield env.process(res_func)


def do_FA(env, fa, tray):

    # wrap the function in a lambda fuction that assigns the paramerters
    # creating a function with no parameters to pass to the helper funciton

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} starting FA {tray}')

    yield env.process(use_resource(env, fa.resource1, fa.do_process1(tray)))
    yield env.process(use_resource(env, fa.resource2, fa.do_process2(tray)))

    # not calling do_process1 creates a generator that is passed to the helper
    

    # with fa.resource1.request() as request:
    #     yield request
    #     yield env.process(fa.do_process1(tray))

    # with fa.resource2.request() as request:
    #     yield request
    #     yield env.process(fa.do_process2(tray))

def run_FA(env):
    fa = FA(env)
    tray = 0

    while True:
        tray += 1
        env.process(do_FA(env, fa, tray))
        time_between_trays = 12
        yield env.timeout(time_between_trays)

env = simpy.Environment()
env.process(run_FA(env))
env.run(until=20000)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using getattr and setattr.

This is the *resources* definition.

*resources* is a dictionary with the name of resource as the key and qty as the value.

```
class FA(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
    self.resources = {k: v for k, v in read_csv(RES_FILE, False)}
        for res, qty in self.resources.items():
            setattr(self, res, simpy.Resource(env, int(qty)))
```

And in *do_FA*

```
request = getattr(fa, res).request()
```

Where *res* is the resource name as a string variable.